# Error when adding custom validation for angular reactive form

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I've created a simple custom validation function.

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export function firstLeterUpperCase():ValidatorFn{
    return (control:AbstractControl) =>{
        const value = <string>control.value;
        if(!value) return;
        if(value.length === 0) return;
        const firstLetter = value[0];
        if(firstLetter  !== firstLetter.toUpperCase())
        {
            return{
                  firstLeterUpperCase:{
                   message:"First letter must be uppercase."
               }
            }
        }
        return
    }
}
```

but I've got the following error. Not sure where I'm doing wrong.

Error: src/app/validators/firstLetterValidator.ts:4:5 - error TS2322: Type '(control: AbstractControl) => {} | undefined' is not assignable`enter code here` to type 'ValidatorFn'.
Type '{} | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ValidationErrors | null'.

Comment: From the error message, `ValidatorFn` type must return `ValidationErrors` or `null`, but you have returned `undefined` (`return;` is same as `return undefined;`). Maybe it should be `return null;` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a simple function that does what you need:

```
export function firstLetterUppercase(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    return /^[A-Z]/.test(control.value) ? null : { firstLetterUpperCase: true };
  };
}
```

Where we use the regex `/^[A-Z]/` to test the `control.value` and see if it has the first letter uppercase. The function will return `null` if there are no errors otherwise it returns `{ firstLetterUpperCase: true }`. Then [associate the validator to your input](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) (read it) and show or hide the error message directly in the template.

```
<div class="error-message" *ngIf="yourInputName.errors.firstLetterUpperCase">
 First letter must be uppercase.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using the newest version of Angular. You can try this code:

```
 import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";  


 export function firstLetterUppercase(): ValidatorFn {
        return (control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null => {
            const value  = <string>control.value;
            if(!value) return null;
            if(value.length === 0) return null;
    
            const firstLetter = value[0];
            if(firstLetter !== firstLetter.toUpperCase()){
                return {
                    firstLetterUppercase : {
                        message: 'The first letter must be uppercase'
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about what's the problem in the OP's code and how your code fixes it?